# How can I see the loggedin users that have used 'su'

Tags: linux, su

If I use a login shell to login as root
then 'who' or 'users' commands
will show an entry for the root user.
However If I login with user1 and then use:

```
'su - root'
```

Then the 'who' and 'users' command will not show an entry for root.

Is there a way to find out whether there is a logged-in user in my system that has currently switched to root (or to any other account)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx to Davide Berra's answer, I think I have found what I was looking for.

```
> who | sort -k2 > /tmp/whoresult
> pgrep -x su | xargs -i ps hu -p{} | awk '{printf $7 " ";for (i=11; i<=NF; i++) printf $i " "; printf "\n"}' | sort -k1 | join -1 2 -2 1 /tmp/whoresult -
```

The output is something like:

```
pts/3 user1 2013-02-06 16:35 (:0.0) su - root    #logged in as user1 and executed 'su - root'
pts/5 user1 2013-02-06 16:51 (:0.0) su           #logged in as user1 executed 'su'
tty2 root 2013-02-06 17:07 su - user1            #logged in as root and executed 'su - user1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `/var/log/secure` file.

Search for line like this:

```
Feb  6 14:12:09 myhost su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=999)
```

the `uid` at the end of the string is the one of the original user.

Otherwise you can search for shells that executed `su` command and check who's the owner.

```
pgrep su | \
xargs -i sh -c "ps -p {} -o ppid=" | \
xargs -i ps -p {} -f
```

The result will be the uids of who is currently running `su`

*I'm sure there's a more elegant method but nothing better comes to my mind right now.*

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is very close to what I want. If I could find the account on which they have switched to (using su), would be great.